# My GET requests re-direct correctly locally but not online.. :/

Tags: php

```
======== Projet_4/index.php =======

<?php
    session_start();
    include('./mvc/controller/main.php');

    if(!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['rePassword'])){
        $userAction = new ActionsUser();
        $userAction->subscribeUser();
    } elseif(!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $userAction = new ActionsUser();
        $_SESSION['pseudoUser']  = $_POST['pseudo'];
        $userAction->connectionUser();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['disconnectUser'])){
        ?><script>alert('Vous êtes déconnecté !')</script><?php
        $disconnect = new ActionsUser();
        $disconnect->disconnectUser();
    }

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee" rel="stylesheet">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/phoneFormat.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabFormat.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktopFormat.css">
    <title>Blog du Writer</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1 id="titleBody">Le Wr!ter</h1>
        <p>
            <img src="img/writer.png" id="iconTitle" title="Contactez-nous !" alt="iconTitle">
        </p>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="li1"><a href="index.php">Accueil</a></li>
            <li class="li2"><a href="#">Inscription</a></li>
            <li class="li3"><a href="#">Livre d'or</a></li>
            <li class="li4"><a href="#">Chat</a></li>
            <li class="li5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <?php
        include('./mvc/view/slider.php');
        displaySlider();
    ?>

    <?php
        include('./mvc/view/displayForm.php');
        displayForm();
    ?>


</body>

</html>


======= Projet_4/mvc/model/checkForm.php ========

<?php

    class CheckForm {

        public function memberExistInscription(){
            include('./mvc/model/databaseConnect.php');
            if (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['rePassword']) ) {
                $pseudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
                $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
                $req = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users 
                                      WHERE email= ? OR pseudo= ?
                                     ");
                $req->execute(array($email, $pseudo));
                $users = $req->fetch();

                if($users['pseudo'] == $pseudo){
                    $this->errorSubscribeExistPseudo();
                }elseif ($users['email'] == $email){
                    $this->errorSubscribeExistEmail();
                }
                elseif ($users['pseudo'] == null && $users['email'] == null){
                    $this->insertUser();
                }

            } else{
                $this->errorUser();
            }
        }

        public function memberExistConnection(){
            include('./mvc/model/databaseConnect.php');
            if (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
                $pseudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
                $passwordSalt = htmlspecialchars(hash("sha512" ,"azzjfa".$pseudo."15z1d"));
                $password = htmlspecialchars(hash("sha256" , $_POST['password'].$passwordSalt));

                $req = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users
                                      WHERE pseudo= ?
                                      ");
                $req->execute(array($pseudo));
                $users = $req->fetch();

                if($users['pseudo'] == $pseudo && $users['password'] == $password){
                    if(!isset($_COOKIE['pseudo'])){
                        $timerCookie = 60 ;
                        setcookie('pseudo', "a48f484fz" , $timerCookie);
                    }
                    $this->connectUser();
                }elseif($pseudo == $users['pseudo'] && $users['password'] != $password){
                    $this->errorUserPassword();
                }elseif ($users['pseudo'] == null){
                    $this->errorUser();
                }
            }
        }

        public function insertUser(){
            include('./mvc/model/databaseConnect.php');
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }
            elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            }
            else {
                $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }

            if (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['rePassword']) ){
                $pseudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
                $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
                $passwordSalt = hash("sha512" , "azzjfa".$pseudo."15z1d");
                $password = hash("sha256" , $_POST['password'].$passwordSalt);

                $req = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (pseudo , email , password, passwordSalt, ip)
                                VALUES (? , ? , ?, ?, ?)");
                $req->execute(array($pseudo , $email , $password, $passwordSalt, $ip_address));
            }
        }

        public function connectUser(){
            header("Location:./?success=1");
            exit();
        }

        public function disconnectUser(){
            header("Location:./?disconnectUser=1");
            exit();
        }

        public function errorUser(){
            header("Location:./?error=1");
            exit();
        }

        public function errorUserPassword(){
            header("Location:./?errorPassword=1");
            exit();
        }

        public function errorSubscribeExistPseudo(){
            header("Location:./?errorSubscribeExistPseudo=1");
            exit();
        }

        public function errorSubscribeExistEmail(){
            header("Location:./?errorSubscribeExistEmail=1");
            exit();
        }

    }


====== Projet_4/mvc/view/displayForm.php =====

<?php

function displayForm(){

        echo '  

           <div id="containerForms">

                <form action="./index.php" method="POST" id="formSubscribe">

                     <h3 id="titleSubscription">S\'inscrire</h3><br>
                     <div class="col">
                         <label for="inputText">Pseudo</label>
                         <input type="text" name="pseudo" class="form-control" placeholder="Pseudo" required>
                     </div><br>

                     <div class="col">
                         <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">E-mail</label>
                         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="nom@exemple.com">
                     </div><br>

                     <div class="col">
                         <label for="inputPassword4">Mot de passe</label>
                         <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
                     </div><br>

                     <div class="col">
                         <label for="inputPassword4">Saisir à nouveau</label>
                         <input type="password" name="rePassword" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
                     </div><br>

                     <div class="col">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="submitSubscribe">Envoyer</button>
                     </div>

                </form>

                <form action="./index.php" id="formConnection" method="POST">

                    <h3 id="titleConnection">Se connecter</h3><br>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Pseudo</label>
                        <input type="text" name="pseudo" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" placeholder="KevinDu12 ">
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="inputPassword4">Mot de passe</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
                    </div><br>

                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Envoyer</button>
                    </div>

                </form>

           </div>
        ';


}
?>


=========== Projet_4/mvc/model/error.php ============

<?php

    if(isset($_GET['error'])){
        echo '<script>alert("Erreur");</script>';
        echo 'Error';
    } elseif(isset($_GET['success'])){
        include ('./mvc/view/redirectUser.php');
        $userSpace = new RedirectUser();
        $userSpace->checkAccessUser();
        echo '<script>alert("Success");</script>';
        echo 'Success';
    } elseif(isset($_GET['errorPassword'])){
        echo '<script>alert("Mauvais mot de passe");</script>';
        echo 'Error Password';
    } elseif(isset($_GET['errorSubscribeExistPseudo'])){
        echo '<script>alert("Désolé ce Pseudo est déja pris.. :/");</script>';
        echo 'Error Subscribe Exist Pseudo';
    } elseif(isset($_GET['errorSubscribeExistEmail'])){
        echo '<script>alert("Désolé cette Email est déja prise.. :/");</script>';
        echo 'Error Subscribe Exist Email';
    }


======= Projet_4/mvc/model/databaseConnect.php =====


<?php

        $host_name = 'localhost';
        $database = 'writer';
        $user_name = 'root';
        $password = '';

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$database;", $user_name, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Erreur!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }


============ Projet_4/mvc/controller/actionsUser.php

<?php

class ActionsUser {

    public function receptForm(){
        include('./mvc/model/checkForm.php');
    }

    public function subscribeUser(){
        $this->receptForm();
        $subscribeUser = new CheckForm();
        $subscribeUser->memberExistInscription();
    }

    public function connectionUser(){
        $this->receptForm();
        $connect = new CheckForm();
        $connect->memberExistConnection();
    }

    public function disconnectUser(){
        $this->receptForm();
        $disconnect = new CheckForm();
        $disconnect->disconnectUser();
    }

}
?>
```

=========== My Problem ========

Once the project hosted online I am not directed to the pages I want, my requests in GET do not appear in the URL, no alert () while local no worries .. My code is not not commented and being beginner nothing is very organized, it's a bit bazard .. against the database works locally and online .. Registration and connection work .. I do not understand at all .. O__ *

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with emphasis on "minimal". There is most likely a lot of code which is not relevant to your question. In fact, you should remove parts of the code until the error is gone or a different error occurs. Use normal debug techniques like `echo`/`var_dump()` to see what your script is doing and which `if` statement is called. Also, check the HTTP headers of your request in your browser (most likely in F12 or something called "developer tools") so see where the redirect is going, if there is any redirect at all.

Comment: Thank you Progman I will follow your advice, isolated the part of code that is problematic. If necessary I will come back .. Thank you again;)